# LWJGL/OpenGL Java Matrix4f Taking up large amounts of memory

Tags: java, opengl, memory, matrix, lwjgl

I am currently making a 3D game engine in LWJGL and recently implemented Skeletal Animation. I made every joint have matrices(Matrix4f) to represent position and rotation, I noticed that my game became very choppy within a few minutes, and decided to comment out the skeletal animation code, and no frame loss. I then assumed that it could either be:

- a. Memory Leak (I hope not) or
- b. Graphics card (I am running on a MacBook Air, 4GB RAM, Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 6000 1536 MB, Processor: 1.6 GHz Intel Core i5)

I then used JProfiler to investigate into memory usage. The graph shows mountains (max used memory: 27.18MB min free memory: 34.77 MB)

I then looked at the live memory and at the top (most of the time) was Matrix4f using 623 kB of memory, and char[] sometimes taking the lead with 642 kB of memory.

This is the first project I have invested ~1 year in, so I don't know very much about this, so is it a graphics card thing, or memory? Should I be worried? What can I do to make it run better?

Comment: Welcome to the world of managed memory languages :-). What you're seeing is the garbage collector cleaning up your temporary variables. In a nutshell, all the matrices you create have to be freed at some point. The freeing is done by the garbage collector, which pauses your game for a while in order to find out which matrices are still in use, and which can be freed. If there's a large amount of free-able stuff, this can take quite a while, and your game will "hang". Solving this is a matter of reducing local allocations, look through your animation code and remove all unnecessary news.

Comment: Also, the chars your seeing are strings. You're allocating too many strings, likely because you are doing "calculations" with them (say string + string), there's ways around this, look at the StringBuffer class. Also, memory leaks in java are very hard to produce, even impossible depending on your definition of "memory leak". If you want I can type up a more complete answer, but I'm supposed to be working right now, so leave a message :-)

Comment: If I can add anything to that, try to reuse data between frames, and try to use arrays over ArrayLists for large buffers of data. In my case both of those things helped significantly with memory usage.

Comment: @Bartvbl That's great advice, but I'd recommend first trying presized ArrayLists before moving straight to arrays, this requires less code and is similarly garbage-free. This can be done by passing an initial capacity to the arraylist constructor. The list will now be preallocated with that size, and reallocation will not happen until that size is exceeded. If the initial capacity is sufficient, this will never happen, and the array list will behave like an array. Also note that arraylists, afaik, do not reduce their own size, which makes it rare that they are the cause of repeated GC hangs

Comment: @TWT: ArrayLists are certainly capable of preallocating space for a specific number of elements. However, in my experience it's far superior to use arrays directly in the context of large chunks of data for two reasons. First, as using ArrayLists on their own to store your data will inevitably end up exploding your memory usage due to JVM overhead of allocating internal arrays in the ArrayList (in addition to heap space), you often need to predetermine your buffer sizes anyway. Second, using arrays removes the internal capacity checks ArrayList does when inserting new elements.

Comment: @TWT: I realise it's not entirely the scope of this question, but it's where I personally had to wrangle most with the garbage collector. With rendering the trick is to minimise the creation of objects in a tight loop, which means those ArrayLists should not be created every frame in the first place if not strictly necessary.

Comment: @lougehrig10: Can you please show some of your Java/Shader code to show how you have implemented your skeletal animation? Peaks and valleys are also normal when it comes to java memory usage, so it's not necesarily the problem. Data usage in the order of Kb's seems a bit low to me to be a significant problem for the garbage collector to handle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132927/discussion-between-bartvbl-and-twt).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WakqwRVk should have enough information, I think...

Comment: What I can understand is that when I Create an animation I need to have a set number of joints, and then when I want to interpolate, I just do the math and replace the matrix in the joint instead of creating a new matrix correct?

Comment: I think the issue might be performing 50 matrix multiplications for every single vertex in your model. With such a long loop you get a lot of branching too, which on a GPU are costly operations. One thing you could try is to disable is the shader side of the skeletal animation (don't do the calculations, keep the inputs), to see if it's the CPU side giving you issues.

Comment: Ok, I turned off animation (loads matrix, but no math) and it still was choppy, but if I rendered it with the normal entity shader, it didn't lag. The normal entity shader does not load the join transforms, however. I did send the code over to some friends, one who has a graphics card and 8GB RAM and he said it ran smoothly for him, the other friend does not have a graphics card and he also has 8GB of RAM and he said it was a little choppy for his computer